# Ansible cannot copy a file. Probably permissions

Tags: ansible, proxmox

**I want to copy a new certificate to Proxmox with Ansible.**

### My setup

`.ssh/config` is modified so `ssh machine` will log in with root.

`scp /Users/dir/key.pem /etc/pve/nodes/machine/pve-ssl.key` works fine.

### Problem

Ansible fails. I'm running this on an up-to-date macbook. ansible --version is `ansible 2.2.1.0`.

machine.yml

```
- hosts: machines
  vars:
    ca_dir: /Users/dir/

  - name: copy a pve-ssl.key
    copy:
      src="{{ ca_dir }}/key.pem"
      dest=/etc/pve/nodes/machine/pve-ssl.key
```

### Permissions?

This works fine:

```
- hosts: machines
  vars:
    ca_dir: /Users/dir/

  - name: copy a pve-ssl.key
    copy:
      src="{{ ca_dir }}/key.pem"
      dest=/root/pve-ssl.key
```

So it's a permissions problem, but why. Ansible is entering my machine with root - `ansible machine -m shell -a 'who'`.

Probably something to do with group permissions, since

```
$ ls -la /etc/pve/nodes/machine/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root www-data    0 Feb 26 01:35 .
[...]
$ ls -la /root
drwx------  5 root root  4096 Feb 26 12:09 .
[...]
```

How can I copy the file with ansible?

Comment: The question is how to fix the problem. I guess it's not obvious. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If the question is "what is the problem?" then the answer is:

  It's because of the `/dev/fuse` filesystem mounted on `/etc/pve` (Ansible just cannot move the file from `/tmp` to the branch of `/etc/pve`, just like a simple `mv /tmp/file /etc/pve` command fails).
- If the question is "how to deal with the problem?" then:

  Copy the files elsewhere (`/home/user`) with Ansible and then copy the files using the command module on Proxmox and delete the originals.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the easily reproducible example.

Answer (score -1):

You could also first touch the file and then copy it:

```
- name: touch empty file
  file:
    path: /etc/pve/nodes/machine/pve-ssl.key
    state: touch

- name: copy a pve-ssl.key
        copy:
          src: "{{ ca_dir }}/key.pem"
          dest: /etc/pve/nodes/machine/pve-ssl.key
```